# VideoView (building my own video view)

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

```
private void openVideo() {
        if (mUri == null || mSurfaceHolder == null) {
            // not ready for playback just yet, will try again later
            return;
        }
        // Tell the music playback service to pause 
        // TODO: these constants need to be published somewhere in the framework.
        Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "pause");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(i);

        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mSizeChangedListener);
            mIsPrepared = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "reset duration to -1 in openVideo");
            mDuration = -1;
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mBufferingUpdateListener);
            mCurrentBufferPercentage = 0;
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            attachMediaController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            return;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I got this code from GrepCode ([VideoView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/VideoView.java)).I would like to add Mute and unmute functions on my videoview hence am trying to create a new videoview.But due to this mContext variable i am not able to set the path for my mediaplayer.

Purpose of Mute and Unmute: To play other audios with the same audio..

I want to access the Mediaplayer for mute and unmute function and hence am not overriding my videoview class. 
Am a newbie to android so suggest me some methods to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you start from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html and add your features you need

Comment: the problem is the code is already and i am allowed only to add new code (not allowed to change the previous code). so this patch work. and i know how it is done by the method you suggested.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129814/usable-videoview-source-code-for-android-2-2/11130677#11130677) helps.

Comment: i removed the                                                   Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "pause");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(i);                                part will that cause any problem in future because it works fine..